# Changing this inline JavaScript/jQuery to work from external file?

Tags: jquery

I'm not much of a coder to be fair so this is probably really simple.

I've moved this piece of code from inline to external but since doing so it has stopped working.

I'm wondering what it is that I need to change to make it work.

```
function lazy_load_html() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        if (navigator.platform == "iPad") return;
        jQuery("#content,#footer").find("img").lazyload({
            effect:"fadeIn",
            placeholder: "http://www.domain.com/long-path/grey.gif"
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is this the complete copy from the external file? If it is, you're missing the closing `}`.

Comment: where are you calling lazy_load_html()?

Comment: HEy James thanks for your response. Removing that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: That was thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder

Answer (score 1):

From your comment to James:

> It seems like there's something missing from it. I thought a "}" but not matter where I add one of them it doesn't work :-(

The missing `}` should be at the end:

```
    function lazy_load_html() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            if (navigator.platform == "iPad") return;
            jQuery("#content,#footer").find("img").lazyload({
                effect:"fadeIn",
                placeholder: "http://www.domain.com/long-path/grey.gif"
            });
        });
    }
//  ^-- here
```

Other things to check:

1) You'll want to be sure that the `script` tag for this external file is *after* the jquery.js one.

2) Make sure something somewhere is actually calling the `lazy_load_html` function, or get rid of it. If getting rid of it, just remove the first and last line of the above, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if (navigator.platform == "iPad") return;
    jQuery("#content,#footer").find("img").lazyload({
        effect:"fadeIn",
        placeholder: "http://www.domain.com/long-path/grey.gif"
    });
});
```

There's no particular reason you need to have it in its own function, the `jQuery(document).ready` part already handles deferring actually doing the hooking up of the images for you.

Comment: I added that in and it still doesn't work.. It has me really confused because they are in the right order too Jquery then the file that has this in it.

Comment: This worked like a charm. I think also chaning the order in the no jquery.js file helped too. Not sure if it did but everything you referenced made it work. Now working sweet as. Thanks very much dude. Highly appreciated and have a great day dude and a happy future. :D Maybe we'll meet one day again in the mounds of questions on StackOverflow hehe. Great work. So happy now I can go to bed knowing it's working and saving my bandwidth.

Comment: @Mark: Glad that helped. If this answered your question, please click the empty checkmark to the left of the beginning of this answer. That marks your question as "answered". (More here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference in the execution of code inline or in an external file.

Have you changed the place where you include the external file - it should be in the same place as the inline code to be sure it will do exactly the same thing.

Are you sure you are correctly including the external file - if not can you post how you are doing that?

Comment: All other javascript in the external file works fine apart from this code.. :-( It seems like there's something missing from it. I thought a "}" but not matter where I add one of them it doesn't work :-(